# How can one extract resources from a New Executable?

Tags: tools, ne

I'm trying to extract menus and other stuff from a [New Executable (NE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Executable), i.e. the ones from Windows' 16-bit times. The tools I find (e. g. ResourceTuner) work for [PEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) only.

Any idea for tools to facilitate the resource extraction? Could be several steps too, e.g.  one program extracting the raw resources, one displaying them in a proper form.

Comment: meta-question: why did it tell me my question was subjective, based just on the title?
request: could someone retag "pe-resources" to "resources" or "ne-resources", because I don't have the reputation to do so (need 150, just upvote so I can do it myself ;) )

Comment: because it started with 'how can you' ?

Comment: @Ange how is that subjective?

Comment: I don't know, but their subjectivity detector definitely triggers on 'how can you' ;)

Comment: @Ange: "how can you" and "how can one" are near synonymous. No? Fixed up the question a bit. It's great, because it touches a topic not too often found anymore these days.

Comment: "How can you kill puppies" could either be a subjective, emotional question, or a request for objective, instructional material.

Comment: @AshRj How is resources a very generic tag? I wanted it to address specifically resources from windows executables. Maybe this question should be tagged [tag:pe-resources], although it's not about PE resources.

Comment: Resources could refer to resources being used by Windows or Linux or Mac executables thus it cannot by itself used for a question. See [meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) for more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should try [OpenWatcom](http://www.openwatcom.org/index.php/Main_Page)'s `Resource Editor`, and also [Hiew](http://hiew.ru) and [HT Editor](http://hte.sourceforge.net/) albeit these 2 won't likely display them in proper form, as they are just NE-supporting hex editors.

OpenWatcom includes a full toolchain for Win-16 and dos development.

Comment: I took a look at the OpenWatcom, looks very promising. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps a bit more detail would be in order? Especially since you only mention OpenWatcom, not exactly which of the tools to use.

Answer (score 6):

A great resource for old tools is the [SAC server](http://www.sac.sk/). From a quick search [Resource Grabber](ftp://ftp.sac.sk/pub/sac/utilprog/resgrabr.exe) seems to support NE resources, though the UI is annoying to use.

Another options is [eXeScope](http://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA003525/emysoft.htm#6) (shareware).

Also, long time ago I found somewhere a tool with the name `dresplay.exe`. I don't have it at hand right now and Google doesn't seem to know about it...